# Вывод текущего времени

Tags: c#

Возникла небольшая трудность. Хочу сделать, чтобы время шло в секундах, а мне только показывает в момент запуска программы статику :( Делал так:

```
public void date()
        {
            DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;

            while(true)
            {
                label1.Text = date1.ToString();
            }
        }
```

В доках ничего нет для дескопа! И ещё хочу, чтобы, например, в label каком-то по нажатию кнопки пошел секундомер, до тех пор, пока не закроешь программу. Вот тут пробовал, не получилось, код не покажу ибо говнокод написал какой-то.

И ещё!
Создаю PictureBox, сую туда картинку, а программа ругается! Как все это правильно сделать? Спасибо!

Comment: Ничего не понял, если честно. Сформулируйте вопрос нормально. Пример работы с таймером вам уже написали. Что значит "время в секундах"? Просто перевести из милисекунд в секунды или что?

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понял суть вопроса. Вот пример работы с таймером и кнопкой... С PictureBox что не так?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();           
        }

        Timer timer;
        int counter;

        public void initTimer()
        {
            label1.Text = "0";
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 1000;
            timer.Start();
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timerTick);
            counter = 0;
        }

        private void timerTick(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
        {
            counter++;
            label1.Text = counter.ToString();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            initTimer();
        }
    }
}
```